# Including Stripe card info in ajax form removes authenticity_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication, stripe-payments, csrf

I have a form_tag using Ajax to save a new user card with Stripe. It renders a Stripe card form, passes the input to a controller method, and then is supposed to serve a js file. It works without the Stripe stuff, but with it, I'm getting authentication issues.

Here's the basic code:

```
<%= form_tag(save_card_path, id:'payment-form', remote: true) do %>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>
  <button id="submit-card" class="submit-btn">Save Card</button>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var stripe = Stripe('<%= @stripe_public %>');
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  var style = {
    base: {
      // Add your base input styles here. For example:
      fontSize: '20px',
      color: "#32325d",
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the customer that there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }
</script>
```

## card_controller.rb

```
def save_card
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

## save_card.js.erb

```
$("html").hide();
```

So like I said, without the Stripe code everything works fine, and an `authenticity_token` is present in the params, but the code as I wrote it above gives the following error:

```
    def handle_unverified_request
      raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
    end
```

with only the params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "stripeToken"=>"<token>"}
```

When I add the option `authenticity_token: true` to the form, the params once again contain an `authenticity_token`, but now when it gets to the `format.js` line, I get the error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

I've run into a similar problem before while trying to upload files in forms via Ajax, but I discovered the [remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) gem, and that solved it. But it doesn't appear to help in this case.

Does anyone know why including a Stripe field would get rid of my authenticity_token, and why even with an authenticity_token, the js format isn't recognized?

---

### EDIT:

Jquery-ujs is included via the line `//= require jquery_ujs` in my `application.js`, the line `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` is included in `application.html.erb`, and my source code includes the lines

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<TOKEN>" />
```

This is the case whether my ajax call works or not.

### UPDATE:

This is my full log when I add the option `authenticity_token: true`:

> Started POST "/save_card" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-20 00:07:04 +0100
>
> Processing by UsersController#save_card as HTML
>
> Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"[LONG TOKEN]",
>   "post"=>"47", "transaction"=>"bid",
>   "stripeToken"=>"[STRIPE TOKEN]"}
>
> User Load (0.9ms)
>
> SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY
>   "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> (0.3ms)  BEGIN
>   SQL
>
> (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "cards" ("stripe_customer_id", "brand",
>   "last4", "exp_month", "exp_year", "user_id", "created_at",
>   "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id" 
>   [["stripe_customer_id", "[STRIPE TOKEN]"], ["brand", "Visa"],
>   ["last4", "4242"], ["exp_month", "4"], ["exp_year", "2024"],
>   ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2020-02-19 23:07:05.246789"],
>   ["updated_at", "2020-02-19 23:07:05.246789"]]
>
> (2.8ms)  COMMIT
>
> Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 672ms (ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)
>
> ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat): 
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:485:in `save_card' Started GET
>   "/serviceworker.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-20 00:07:05 +0100 Started
>   GET "/serviceworker.js" for ::1 at 2020-02-20 00:07:21 +0100

and this is my log when I remove `authenticity_token: true`:

> Started POST "/save_card" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-20 00:33:17 +0100
>
> Processing by UsersController#save_card as HTML
>
> Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓", "post"=>"47", "transaction"=>"bid",
>   "stripeToken"=>"[STRIPE TOKEN]"} Can't verify CSRF token
>   authenticity. Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord:
>   0.0ms)
>
> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
>   (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):    actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:195:in
>   `handle_unverified_request' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:227:in`
>   handle_unverified_request' devise (4.7.0)
>   lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:255:in `handle_unverified_request'
>   actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:222:in`
>   verify_authenticity_token' activesupport (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
>   activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:197:in`block (2
>   levels) in halting' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in
>   <module:Callbacks>' activesupport (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in`block in halting'
>   activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in
>   invoke_before' activesupport (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in`each' activesupport (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before' activesupport
>   (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in`run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in
>   process_action' activesupport (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in`block in instrument'
>   activesupport (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
>   activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in`
>   instrument' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in`process_action'
>   activerecord (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in`process' actionview (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in`dispatch' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in`dispatch' actionpack
>   (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
>   actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in`block
>   in serve' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in`serve' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
>   serviceworker-rails (0.6.0) lib/serviceworker/middleware.rb:35:in`
>   call' remotipart (1.4.3) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
>   warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in`block in call' warden
>   (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch' warden (1.2.8)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call' rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in
>   `call' rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in`call' rack
>   (2.0.7) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call' rack (2.0.7)
>   lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in`context' rack (2.0.7)
>   lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in`call' activerecord
>   (5.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call' actionpack
>   (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in`block in
>   call' activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in`call' actionpack
>   (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
>   actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in`call'
>   web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
>   web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in`block in
>   call' web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
>   web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in`call'
>   actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
>   railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in`call_app' railties
>   (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call' activesupport
>   (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in
>   `tagged' activesupport (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in`tagged' railties (5.1.7)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call' sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
>   lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in`call' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call' actionpack
>   (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in`call' rack
>   (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call' rack (2.0.7)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in`call' activesupport (5.1.7)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in
>   `call' actionpack (5.1.7)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`call' actionpack
>   (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call' rack
>   (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in`call' railties (5.1.7)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call' puma (3.12.1)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in`call' puma (3.12.1)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request' puma (3.12.1)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:474:in`process_client' puma (3.12.1)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run' puma (3.12.1)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in`block in spawn_thread' Started GET
>   "/serviceworker.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-20 00:33:18 +0100

Comment: Hi, I am guessing your issue caused by ajax. The authenticity_token in ajax call normally automatically added by jquery-ujs, which reads the token from the meta elements added to your header by csrf_meta_tags.

Just check the jquery-ujs and csrf_meta_tags.

Comment: Are you including the `authenticity_token` on the HTML page and is it being submitted with the form?

Comment: @FeifeiXiong jquery-ujs is included via the code "//= require jquery_ujs", and the "csrf-param" and "csrf-token" metatags both show up in my source code. I updated my question to show the full code.

Comment: @floatingLomas I updated my question to show the full code, but yes, my source code always has the "csrf-param" and "csrf-token" metatags, but when the Stripe code is there, the authenticity_token param is not subitted with the form.

Comment: @JoeMorano  try this `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

Comment: @FeifeiXiong That's already included in my layouts/application.html.erb. Or are you suggesting I put that right on my form?

Comment: @JoeMorano  Where did you put `<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />` and
`<meta name="csrf-token" content="<TOKEN>" />` in your source code, could you remove them and try again, because `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` Returns meta tags “csrf-param” and “csrf-token” with the name of the cross-site request forgery protection parameter and token. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper.html

Comment: I didn't add them, they're generated by the line "<%= csrf_meta_tags %>", so they only appear in the generated HTML of my webpage. They're not in my actual codebase.

Comment: @JoeMorano, Did you have <%= javascript_include_tag
‘application’, ‘data-turbolinks-track’: ‘true’ %> in your layout file?

Comment: @FeifeiXiong I'm sorry I'm only responding now - I previously had "<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>" in my layout file, but I replaced it with "<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'true' %>", and either way, I'm still getting the errors.

Comment: @JoeMorano Can u update yr request log ? the issue is not `authenticity_token`. And did u minimize controller `save_card ` method?

Comment: @7urkm3n I added my request log to the question. And I'm not sure what you mean by minimizing my controller method. The method is in my users_controller.rb file, exactly as I wrote it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Rails 5.X and you have `//= require rails-ujs` in your `application.js` file

Instead of `form.submit()`, using `Rails.fire(form, 'submit')` will allow you the submit the form via Ajax

Comment: That does appear to have solved it! Do you know what the difference is between the two commands?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following,

Add the option `authenticity_token: true` to the form, then the params once again contain an authenticity_token. And rename your `save_card.js` to `save_card.js.erb`.

Comment: Hi @JoeMorano, does the same error refers to `ActionController::UnknownFormat`? Because `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` is the error with `authenticity_token`, and from my previous experience, `ActionController::UnknownFormat` is not caused by authenticity_token. And could you post the detailed error log for `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

Comment: I updated my question to include the logs. When I add "authenticity_token: true" to my form, I get "ActionController::UnknownFormat", but I have no idea why. In the past, whenever I've had trouble with my authenticity token (usually when uploading files) it always lead to UnknownFormat errors too.

Comment: Your request is not a js request, it is a html request. See this `Processing by UsersController#save_card as HTML`. And in your `save_card` method, there is no html response. However, your form has a remote: true option. What is your rails version? Could you try `<%= form_tag(save_card_path(format: :js), method: :post, id:'payment-form', remote: true) do %>`

Comment: I tried that, and now the request is shown to be javascript in the logs, and I don't get any errors, but the javascript itself now seems to be rendered as HTML. I'm redirected to a page that just prints the contents of my save_card.js.erb file as plain text.

Comment: Hi @JoeMorano Did you solved it with Rails.fire(form, 'submit')?

Comment: It did seem to solve it, but I can't figure out why one wouldn't work and the other would. And thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi @JoeMorano No worries, and this may help. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29811

Answer (score 1):

Keep everything as it was, and just update `.submit()`

The actual issue is sending as `HTML` instead of as `JS` on `form.submit()`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546

```
 //from
 form.submit();

 //to
 form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true}));
```

#### Updated

Previously, You were submitting, then asking to submit it again. OnClick button, get stripe data then submit with my answer. Sample below.

Also, you need to add `disable/enable` for submit button on click, to ignore multiple clicks.

```
...
// Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
  let submitCardBtn = document.getElementById('submit-card');

  submitCardBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

   // disable button
    submitCardBtn.disabled = true;


    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the customer that there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;

        // enable button on false
        submitCardBtn.disabled = false; 
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
   form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true})); 

   // enable button
   submitCardBtn.disabled = false;
  }
```

Comment: Good find. I suspect it has something to do with the "bubbles: true", but this code makes my form submit over and over again in an endless loop, and with "bubbles: false", the original error is back.

Comment: @JoeMorano UPDATED!